# IE and Chrome are requesting that I allow ect.html.gz to be downloaded for some sites

Tags: malware, browser, download

IE and Chrome are requesting that I allow `ect.html.gz` to be downloaded for some sites.
What is this file? Is it dangerous, or is this a malfunction of IE and Chrome?
The problem does not occur with Firefox.

Comment: hmm this sound suspicious....any example on the sites ?

Comment: Sounds bad, see [analysis at malwr.com](https://malwr.com/analysis/NmYzNmJjMTVhYTBlNDUxODg5OTRiYTA0Njg3MTA0OTU/)

Comment: Yes. I have the same issue with Chrome: [http://www.telerik.com/][1]
 
 
   [1]: http://www.telerik.com/